# Weak convergence of subsequences

Tags: convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Could you help me to clarify the following statement:

> Consider a sequence of real-valued random variables $\{X_n\}$ and the
>   real-valued random variable $X$. Suppose that every subsequence of
>   $\{X_n\}$ has a subsequence that converges in distribution to $X$.
>   Then $\{X_n\}$ converges in distribution to $X$.

Comment: Would the statement be clearer if the convergence in distribution was replaced by the convergence of a sequence of real numbers?

Comment: It is still not clear to me why the whole sequence should converge to $X$,